# How to set domainname in RHEL7.3 machine

Tags: linux, ldap, hostname, domain-name

I have to setup domainname right now when i am typing below command i am getting nonne

```
[root@username ~]# domainname
(none)
```

But hostname command giving proper result

```
[root@username ~]# hostname
username
```

I try to add below in `vim /etc/hosts`

```
<Server IP> example.com
```

but even this change wont help me.

I am trying to resolve this issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454271/olcrootpw-can-only-be-set-when-rootdn-is-under-suffix

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you want the `domainname` and not `hostname` or `hostname -d`? The `domainname` is used on hosts with NIS(YP).

If you want to set just the hostname in FQDN form, use following command:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname hostname.example.com
```

And yes, don't forget to put it into /etc/hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but hostname command already giving the result .

Comment: And are you using NIS?

Comment: Sorry but i am newbie in this what is NIS?

Comment: That's the why I'm asking. `domainname` returns the NIS domain. The NIS is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service

Comment: FYI..this is a virual machine inside a organization but i raised this issue due to i am getting issue in the Ldap Configuration .